# How to generate a return type-hint from self?

Tags: python, oop, type-hinting

I'd like to generate the return type hint from a string which is defined on `__init__()` within the class:

```
class MyItem:
    return_type: str = None

    def __init__(self, return_type: str):
        self.return_type = return_type

    def get_item() -> self.return_type:   # <--- Is something like that possible?
        return ...
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Note that you have declared two variables `return_type` for `MyItem`: one is static, and the other is a property of instances. That is: `return_type: str = None` is not modified in your `__init__`, and it is accessed via `MyItem.return_type`. I'm unsure if that is desired.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I doubt it as well. Purpose is code completion in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I don't think so. Type hints are used by [type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Because your classes aren't instantiated until runtime, this won't work.

Consider the following code:

```
class MyItem:
    return_type: str = None

    def __init__(self, return_type: str):
        self.return_type = return_type

    def get_item() -> self.return_type:   # <--- Is something like that possible?
        return ...

a = MyItem("Str")
b = a 
b.return_type = "int"
```

The linter would have to run the constructor for `a`, note that `b` is `a`, and then update the return type where `b`'s return type is updated. I can't see a way for the linter or IDE to check return types without running the code first, and we know that type hints have no effect at runtime. This is a cool idea though. This type of behaviour reminds me of sealed classes in kotlin.